# Netbeans: Can I set rules to open determinate filetypes in determinate tabs?

Tags: netbeans, plugins, tabs, ide

I'm using Netbeans for quite a long time but I'd like to know if I can do the following thing:
I want the IDE to know that certain filetypes must be opened in a determinate tab.
Lets say I have 3 tabs opened (A in the 50% of screen and B,C in the other 50% of screen):

```
[A] [B]
[A] [C]
```

I'd like the IDE to open JS files in the tab A, CSS in tab B and... PHP files in tab C. Or maybe the files from my Project 1 in tab A, files from Project 2 in tab B....

Or something like that, is there any way to make such rules like these?

Thanks in advance :_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works this way for different component types: project tab / files tab / editors / outputs / debugger windows / ... But since all editors share the same space in windowing system (Mode) there is no simple way to do this. Writing a plugin that would do this shuffling on editor open event is non-trivial tasks. You can rearrange them manually though.